# Xlwings UDFs while using frozen Python file

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7, xlwings

I am trying to integrate xlwings with an excel spreadsheet that we use on our network drive. However, I do not want to install Python, Xlwings, or any other modules on any computer except for the developers. In addition, I would like to use UDFs only, we do not have an interest in using Macros. I read here (https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/22i4a1/xlwings_the_easiest_way_to_deploy_your_python/) that there is a way to freeze your python script which would prevent the need for all users to have Python installed. As a result, I used cx_Freeze to freeze my script. Assume I have these files in the "I" drive and that there are no other files: test.xlsm, test.py, test.exe, Dir (folder containing dll and pyd files generated by cx_Freeze. I am using Python 2.7 and xlwings 0.7.2. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This hasn't been implemented yet but there's an open issue: https://github.com/ZoomerAnalytics/xlwings/issues/481

Comment: There is a RESTAPI available now. Could work