# xlwings UDFs and executable python file

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7, xlwings

So I know that xlwings can import User Defined Functions to excel from Python and I have no problems when I do that. I also know that xlwings can run macros based on a frozen (executable) python file which removes the requirement for a user to have python installed. My question is if you can merge the two so that User Defined Functions can be run using only a frozen (executable) python file as its source? If so please elaborate on the settings required to do so since I have not successfully done so. Thank you in advance for your time!

Comment: Whe the duplication of the same question? http://stackoverflow.com/q/37710357/918626

Comment: Pretty much, just trying to figure out if there are some options that are easier than others